# Как сравнить значение из документа и регистра накопления?

Tags: 1с

Задача состоит в следующем: организация продаёт баллоны для дайвинга. Объем баллонов рассчитывается в минутах. Организация проводит заправку и выдачу баллонов пользователю. При выдаче баллонов, если внутри баллона меньше 20%, то должно выдать сообщение о необходимости заправке.

Я создал 3 справочника: клиент, сотрудники и номеклатура, в котором есть реквизит объем(измеряется в числах); 2 документа: заправка и выдача, в документе "выдача" есть табличная часть, в которой реквизиты: баллон, объем, текущийобъем; 1 регистр накопления: остатки, где измерения- баллон, ресурсы - ТекущийОбъемМинуты.

Как я понял при движении по регистру накопления, должно сравниваться объем из документа и текущий объём, пытался написать простое условие в модуле объекта, где процедура проведения, но не работает.

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем в документе выдачи в ТЧ реквизиты "Объем" и "Текущий объем".
А приём баллонов есть? Мне общая архитектура видится так. Баллон имеет объем, нам нужно знать, сколько воздуха в баллоне на какой-то момент времени закачано. Соответственно, этот показатель меняется, когда мы получаем баллон (сколько в нем есть?), заправляем (сколько теперь с учетом заправки?). Так как нужно знать объем по факту (не интересует разрез времени), то можно сделать регистр сведений, непериодический, с измерением "Баллон", ресурсом "ТекущийОбъем". И анализируя его можно будет выводить сообщение.

Comment: @Sagittarius, реквизит "объем" имеет фиксированное значение, например, 100. Реквизит "текущий объем" показывает сколько воздуха в баллоне, он не должен превышать 100 и если меньше 20 процентов от всего объем, то выводит ошибку. Я видел это, так: при проведении документа человек выбирает баллон и автоматически подставляется "объем" , а вручную вводит "текущий объем" и проверяется эти два реквизита, если "текущий объем" < 20% от "объем", то документ провести нельзя и выводит сообщение о нехватка воздуха в баллоне. Но не знаю насколько корректно так делать и как это сделать.

Comment: Это учебная задача?

Comment: @Sagittarius да, но придуманная из головы

Comment: Какой у вас опыт работы с 1С? Только учитесь?

Comment: @Sagittarius да, только начал изучать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150346/discussion-between-sagittarius-and-asd123).

Comment: Напишите мне в telegram (ссылка в профиле)

Comment: @Sagittarius написал в чате обсуждения, в тг не нашёл